# JSON into array regardless of depth

Tags: json, swift

First question here so please bear with me on that one.
I'm trying to do a class that will handle http requests.
The server will definitely reply in JSON so - on top of handling requests - I'd like it to turn the JSON data into dictionaries as well.
As of now, I have this but I find it rather inconvenient ...

```
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] else { return }
```

I want this class to be useful in as many situations as possible. There will be situations in which the server will send 4 or 5d json.

My question is the following :
Can't I convert the json into an array, regardless of the depth it will have, php style?

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Parsed `JSON` data already are dictionaries. You want to convert the data to *objects*, with typed properties, not to keep them as a big heap of untyped data.